# nodejs cannot find module mongodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

My current folder structure looks like this:

Root
|
|--App
|--|--bower_components
|--|--views 
|--|--controllers 
|--|--app.js
|--|--index.html
|--node_modules
|--package.json

I already install the **mongodb** module by

```
npm install mongodb
```

but when I use

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

I got this error message

> Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'

Although I already specified mongoddb in the dependencies modules in package.json.

```
"devDependencies": {
    ....
    "mongodb": "^2.1.7"
  },
```

Any idea why the problem happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Check if the folder for the module is in node_modules.

Comment: Try it:  npm install mongoose

Comment: Make sure the `node_modules` folder is in your `cwd`, the folder where you start your application.

Comment: why dev? install it in production with --save

Answer (score 2):

To debug this problem I suggest the following checklist:

1. Check in the folder `nodes_modules` for the current project, the existence of the `mongodb` folder.
2. If it does not exist, open the `terminal` make sure you are on the root folder of your project, if not type `cd path/to/my/project`;
3. Type `npm install mongodb`
4. Check now if the folder `mongodb` exists in the `node_modules` folder.
5. If exists just run your app. It should work.